# Не могу установить oh my zsh

Tags: ubuntu

[image: Выдаёт такую ошибку, что делать? У меня Ubuntu]

Выдаёт такую ошибку, что делать? У меня Ubuntu

Comment: Не можешь увидеть, что не установлен git?  Oh My Zsh...

Comment: я написал что выдает такую ошибку а хз что делать

Comment: Установить git, например?

Comment: Может git не знает что такое git. Это про вот это https://git-scm.com/

Comment: Я не посмотрел на имя автора, извините.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt(-get) install git`

Написано же, что не установлен git